# What is the "Cars/Index" style with slash in Inertia partial reload?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

What is "Cars"? Model or something else? Index is most probably the controller method. Why is slash used, and what does it mean? Also if **Cars** is referring to the **cars** table, then why is it capitalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Vue:

`Cars` is referring a folder (`resources/js/Pages/Cars`) and `Index` is referring a component (`resources/js/Pages/Cars/Index.vue`).

So doing `return inertia('Cars/Index');` (in a PHP file, for example, one of your controllers) will call the Inertia helper to render that specific component.